# OpenGl Textures

Tags: opengl

im trying to apply 2 textures to my level the code compiles but the levels come out completly white,

```
struct Image 
{
    unsigned long size_x;
    unsigned long size_y;
    char *data;
}

typedef struct Image Image;

const int textureCount = 2;

Image myTextureData[textureCount];
GLuint theTexture[textureCount];

char* textureFilenames0[textureCount] = {"road.bmp"};
char* textureFilenames1[textureCount] = {"building.bmp"};
```

texture loader class

```
void textureLoader() 
{

    /*glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);*/

    glGenTextures(2, theTexture);


    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, theTexture[0]);
    for(int k=0; k < textureCount; k++) 
    {
        if(!imageLoader(textureFilenames0[k], &myTextureData[k])) 
            exit(1);

        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

        gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, myTextureData[k].size_x, myTextureData[k].size_y, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, myTextureData[k].data);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, theTexture[1]);
    for(int k=0; k < textureCount; k++) 
    {
        if(!imageLoader(textureFilenames1[k], &myTextureData[k])) 
            exit(1);

        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

        gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, myTextureData[k].size_x, myTextureData[k].size_y, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, myTextureData[k].data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you called

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

and `glTexCoord2` or `glTexCoordPointer`?

Also, try setting the texture parameters before uploading the data.

Finally, when using loops, you need all the filenames in one array, like

```
char* textureFilenames[textureCount] = {"road.bmp", "building.bmp"};
```

Or you can get rid of the loop and write

```
char* textureFilenames0 = "road.bmp";
char* textureFilenames1 = "building.bmp";
```

But there are not `textureCount` files with the road bitmap inside.

Comment: appreiate that mate, but how does the program know  which file i want to call and where would i call glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

Comment: @rich: The code you have now is wrong.  You need to bind texture#k and then load file#k.  Right now you are loading file0#k into texture#0, your loop looks for two filenames, there's only one, so you end up using a NULL pointer and loading a non-existant file on top of your good texture.  I don't know what your texture loader does when you pass it a NULL filename.  `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` needs to be done before you draw textured geometry.

Comment: You use glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, a_texture_ID) to tell OpenGL, which texture to use. Unfortunately in your code above the texture ID, which is allocated using glGenTextures seems to be placed in a single index global variable. Technically textureLoader should return the value of theTexture, so that you can later, when rendering bind it.

Comment: @datenwolf: It's perfectly reasonable (and more flexible) for a texture loader to be designed to load into the currently bound texture.  That's not the problem, since two textures get allocated and two textures get bound.  The problem is that the texture loader gets called N*N times.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I was referring to @rich's question how to tell the program/OpenGL which texture to use. In it's current implementation textureLoader seems to worth through some global variable.

Comment: the thing im confused about is the binding the texture then loading it, i thought thats what i was doing?

Comment: @rich: Look at your for loop.  `k` takes values of `0` and `1`.  What do you expect `imageLoader(textureFilenames0[k], &myTextureData[k])` to do when `k=0`?  How about when `k=1`?  What about the next for loop, with `imageLoader(textureFilenames1[k], &myTextureData[k])`?